# GTX 280 purple snow on bootup, card works without drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

i have owned a ASUS GTX280 for 3 years now. The card has been great all along but i started having problems 10 days ago. I was playing Diablo 3 for 1 week on max settings no problems, then suddenly my display kept getting some weird purple/colours as soon as i booted and logged into windows. Went into safe mode, updated drivers and it kept crashing.

Formatted PC, fresh windows install with new WHQL drivers again same problem.

Uninstalled nvidia drivers and pc has been running great for 4 days now, ofcourse i cannot run games but everything works on 1680x1050 resolution and i can browse internet,watch movies and use my PC for everything but gaming.
As soon as i install nvidia drivers PC won't boot.

I only wanna game a few hours a week (very busy program with school this month so it might be a blessing that i cannot game) and i would love it if i could keep the card.

I am looking to upgrde later on when i will have time for gaming but i wonder if i could still use the card somehow with different/new drivers (tried older drivers that came with the card on a CD aswell)

tldr: PC works fine with no nvidia drivers (apart from gaming ofc). Once i install WHQL drivers or older ones, cannot even log into windows. Fix?

Comment: I have been monitoring my card's temps and it has always been below 80C even under load so i do not believe it is an overheating problem.

Comment: That appears to be a common problem with that card: [GTX 280 Driver causes colorful snow on my display its kinda pink](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=209008&st=0).  In the end, I think your video card is pooched, get that replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Try older n vidia drivers sometimes helps. I don't know why, but worked on other systems

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after playing SWTOR for about a week. I baked my GTX 280 and I haven't had a problem since. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fpgz-pchOo

I also have avoided any driver set that is newer than 258.96. I've read countless issues with newer drivers with older GPUs. 
http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=209008&st=0

Hope this helps or you can just replace the card as techie007 suggested.